# How dependency injection work for covariance type in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Recently I was working with ASP.net core 3.0 and got stuck.
As we know how constructor inject work for dependency inject in .NET Core.

e.g.

```
public class A: IA{
   private readonly IB<B> iB;
   public A(IB<B> iB){
       this.iB = iB;
   }
}
```

Dependency resolve somehow like below.

```
IB<B> iB = new B();
IA iA = new A(iB);
```

That is fine. i understood but what about "Covariance generic type"

e.g `ILogger<ControllerName>`

See the below Code

```
public class AController {
   private readonly ILogger<AController> iLogger;
   public AController(ILogger<AController> iLogger){
       this.iLogger = iLogger;
   }
}
```

so in this case its looks like `AController` is getting circular reference.
If you look for the defination of `ILogger` it is like

```
ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger { }
```

Covariance generic type.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a circular reference is based on what is currently shown

Comment: @Nkosi is right. Creating an instance for `ILogger<AController>` doesn't require creating an instance _of_ `AController`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: Note that it still **could** create a circular reference **if** your  `ILogger<T>` implementation calls `new T()` somewhere (and I am unsure if the compiler will catch this or not). But you are correct that this isn't inherently a circular reference.

Comment: But suppose if you dont have any dependency injection feature in your framework like asp.net framework then how you will create the object of AController class, as ILogger<AController> is dependent. And class has only one constructor. Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging signature 
public interface ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger
    {
    }

Comment: What class are you using as the implementation of `ILogger<TCategoryName>`? Given the interface there's no requirement that the implementation actually requires an instance of `TCategoryName` so there's no circular dependency.

Comment: If you see my 2nd code snippet i have AController and ILogger<AController>. Same way asp.net core expected. But framework accept my Acontroller as out AController as covariant type.

Comment: Is `ILogger<out TCategoryName>` a class? Its name suggests it's an interface, but if it's a class then `new AController(new ILogger<AController>())` should work if it has a default constructor. If it has some other constructor(s), please add them to your question. If it's an interface then you haven't provided the definition of any classes that implement it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

For `ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger { }`, it would not reference `TCategoryName`, `TCategoryName` will be used as string to indicates `category name` while logging.

You could check the source code for `ILogger` by [Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Logging#logging).

Here is the process.

For `ILogger<AController>`, it is crated by [LoggerFactoryExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/d656c4f7e22d1c0b84cab1b453c50ce73c89a071/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerFactoryExtensions.cs#L20)

```
public static ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>(this ILoggerFactory factory)
{
    if (factory == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
    }
    return new Logger<T>(factory);
}
```

For `new Logger<T>(factory);`, it will get category name with `TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(T), includeGenericParameters: false, nestedTypeDelimiter: '.')`

```
public Logger(ILoggerFactory factory)
{
    if (factory == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
    }

    _logger = factory.CreateLogger(TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(T), includeGenericParameters: false, nestedTypeDelimiter: '.'));
}
```

And then, it will create logger with cateogoryname as parameter

```
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        if (CheckDisposed())
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(LoggerFactory));
        }

        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (!_loggers.TryGetValue(categoryName, out var logger))
            {
                logger = new Logger
                {
                    Loggers = CreateLoggers(categoryName),
                };

                (logger.MessageLoggers, logger.ScopeLoggers) = ApplyFilters(logger.Loggers);

                _loggers[categoryName] = logger;
            }

            return logger;
        }
    }
```

During `CreateLoggers` process, it just use `category name` as string.

For the whole process, it does not create an instace for `TCategoryName`, so it will not get circular reference.

Comment: I am much clean now. Thanks.

Comment: @IstiyakMd If so, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: I m new poster in stackoverflow i don't know how to accept answers, do you have any specific button to accept the answer or just by comments, if so then, Thanks i got answer.

Comment: @IstiyakMd You could refer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)